# Entity Framework Objects Serialization through WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

the situation is as following: while adding an object which has 2 level of details into the database using EF the process works fine on SaveChanges() for the first time since all data is loaded from the database.

I tried to store the lists in Sessions and even ViewState (to avoid any serialization problems)
but when i create a new object and add the details to it , the insert process failed at the web level due a serialization problem

Note : the call to the business and data-layer is routed through WCF service

Comment: Are you modifying the generated entity class in anyway? Could you give a code example?

Comment: Did you have used POCO model in EF or its simple EDMX?

Comment: I suspect you are decoupling your EF objects from the context that created them.
I've seen this kind of issues, don't know if it's your case though...